# javascript: can an object have two sets of keys? and delete work with both?

Tags: javascript, object, pointers, reference, delete-operator

can an object have two sets of keys? and delete work with both?

I'm attempting to understand how to create an object with more than one index (set of reference keys) *so if i delete the object the ref should show undefined*. **I made a function that attempts to explain what I am trying but I would like to know if there is some natural way to produce a ref without my function** and have it return undefined if the object key it refers to was deleted (**unlike my example which does not work**)

```
var o = {
    keys:{},
    obj:{},
    add:function(id,item){
        this.obj[id]=item;
        this.keys[item.color]=this.obj[id];   // < here how can i create a reference/pointer
        }
    }

o.add('dog',{name:'dog',color:'green'});

delete o.obj['dog'];


console.log(o);
```

outputs

```
{
  "keys": {
    "green": {
      "name": "dog","color": "green"
    }
  },
  "obj": {}
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I fully understand what's going on, but it looks like you're assigning into this.fs and trying to delete from this.obj.

Comment: spelling mistake sorry fs should be obj

Comment: [Mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) says delete "removes a property from an object; if no more references to the same property are held, it is eventually released automatically", so I think the answer is no. You would probably have to write your own delete method, similar to how you had to write your own add method.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your need, but why can't you use a second object to 'point to' the one that you want reference using multiple (alternate) keys to reference?  This way when you delete one of the keys, you can still use the other to still get to the referenced object.  However, I think, as Charles, suggested, you're probably going to explicitly track the object with the keys, so that when you delete both (all) of the objects pointing to a particular object, you can then delete that object, too.